# SQLFLUFF skips linting macro files

Tags: sql, jinja2, lint, dbt, sqlfluff

In the last week I've been struggling to understand why SQLFLUFF skips linting macros part of my project. The structure of my project is like this:

```
GCP_Project
|- models
|- macros
|- .sqlfluffignore
|- .sqlfluff
|- dbt_project.yml
|- .pre-commit-config.yaml
|- profiles.yml
```

models are stored inside `models` directory and macros are in the `macros` folder. Templater is set to `dbt` as follows:

```
[sqlfluff]
verbose = 1
templater = dbt
dialect = bigquery
sql_file_exts = .sql
max_line_length = 120
rules = CP01

[sqlfluff:templater]
unwrap_wrapped_queries = true

[sqlfluff:templater:dbt]
target = nonprod

[sqlfluff:templater:jinja]
apply_dbt_builtins = true

[sqlfluff:rules:capitalisation.keywords]
capitalisation_policy = upper
```

after running `pre-commit run --all-files`, while dbt models are linted, macro files are skipped showing this message:
`WARNING    Skipped file /Users/.../macros/sample.sql because it is a macro`

It is worth noting that if I change the templater to `Jinja` only macro files get linted. My need is **to have linter that lints BOTH models and macros** in the project.